# A question about dicumarol

Tags: microbiology, pharmacology, toxicology, vitamins, bacterial-toxins

I know that dicumarol was discovered in moldy sweet clover as it caused hemorrhage in cattles, but if someone had thromboembolic disorders causing uncontrolled thrombosis,would it be fine to eat moldy sweet clover (in case of absence of any means of modern life) especially that it contains other microorganisms?